# Backbone Template element rendering wrong

Tags: backbone.js

```
    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
                template: $('#my-view-template').html(),

                render: function (source) {

                    // compile the Underscore.js template
                    var compiledTemplate = _.template(this.template);

                    // render the template with the model data
                    var data = _.clone(this.model.attributes);
                    var html = compiledTemplate(data);

                    this.template.$(".aVideo")
                    this.$aVideo = this.$('#aVideo');
                    this.$aVideo.attr("href", source);                
                    this.$el.append(html);                
                }
            });

    <script type="text/html" id="my-view-template">

        <div style="border:1px solid firebrick; padding:15px; color:firebrick">
                <a class="btn btn-link" id="aVideo" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px;">View Trailer</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </script>

$.ajax({
            url: '/Movie/Movies',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var movie1 = new Movie({
                        "title": data[i].TITLE,
                        "description": data[i].DESCRIPTION,
                        "storyline": data[i].STORYLINE,
                        "rating": data[i].RATING,
                        "infobar": data[i].INFOBAR,
                        "director": data[i].DIRECTOR,
                        "stars": data[i].STARS
                    });

                    var myView = new MyView({
                        model: movie1
                    });

                    myView.setElement("#content");                    
                    myView.render(data[i].VIDEO);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

Every Video is getting rendered as the last video trailer.
I don't understand why I am getting the last video for every movie

Answer (score -1):

I found an alternative way to my problem. Thx!

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" id="aVideo" target="_blank" href="<%= video %>" style="font-size:15px;">View Trailer</a>
```

Comment: Please share it! The site only works well if people share both questions and answers.